# "10 years into her tenure" Is it grammatical?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> General Motors CEO Mary Barra is **10 years into her tenure** and deep
> into her quest to turn GM into an electric-car powerhouse. WSJ’s Mike
> Colias profiles the CEO and discusses the challenges she’s faced in
> getting her big vision for GM’s future on track.

Can I use a noun in front of the prepostional phrase? If so, what does it mean by "10 years into her tenure"? I guess it means "into her 10-year tenure".

Comment: It means ten years in the position so far. She has been CEO for 10 years.

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice Then, should it be  in the position for ten years? I've never seen this construction in my life.

Comment: It's common.  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22five+years+into+his+tenure%22&newwindow=1&sca_esv=593444387&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&biw=1331&bih=620&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AM9HkKk11JLs2WGNoFzZQqffaeLHeJc4Hw%3A1703436371650&ei=U2CIZfylJ6T8ptQPrqyaoAI&ved=0ahUKEwi8m9H-wqiDAxUkvokEHS6WBiQQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22five+years+into+his+tenure%22&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzIhwiZml2ZSB5ZWFycyBpbnRvIGhpcyB0ZW51cmUiSPsOUKcHWKsMcAB4AJABAJgBUqABsgOqAQE2uAEDyAEA-AEBiAYB&sclient=gws-wiz-books

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice Wow, it's quite common. Can I only use nouns of a period of time in that place?

Comment: The abstract pattern is {number}{units of measure} into {something that the unit of measure applies to}.

Comment: The nail was driven two inches into the plank.

Comment: Six days into the semester.

Comment: And it can be extended figuratively:  six beers into oblivion

Comment: {unit(s) of measure} :    One *year* into her tenure....

Comment: Is that something you found online? Why question it? Did you google "into her tenure".

Comment: Yes, you can. It means that she has been the CEO of General Motors for a period of 10 years. Grammatically, the noun phrase "10 years" is a modifier in the preposition phrase "10 years into her tenure".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly grammatical.  It simply means that she became CEO 10 years ago.  It doesn't mean that the job is limited to 10 years.

There are lots of similar expressions

> He jumped 5 cm over the pole.

> He has travelled 20000 leagues under the sea

> He is a long way beyond the pale.

> He is 3 drinks over the limit.

These all have a number with a unit (or a noun, or some other phrase indicating an amount) followed by a prepostional phrase indicating a location, which may be metaphorical (for example, it might indicate a location in time.)